# I'm flummoxed. In IE10, although these functions are defined immediately above the call to them, they are seen as not defined

Tags: xslt

The following function definition is immediately followed by an input field with a call to it, yet the function is not seen as defined?!

```
<script>
    <![CDATA[
    function SubmitCross()
    {
    var axis1 = "select_flavor" +                document.all.item('axisflavor1').selectedIndex + "_axis1";
                var axis2 = "select_flavor" + document.all.item('axisflavor2').selectedIndex + "_axis2";
                var variable1 = document.all.item(axis1).value.split(".");

                if (variable1[0].indexOf("error") == -1)
                {
                var questionY       = variable1[0].split("-");
                var implicitTypeY   = variable1[1].split("-");
                var flavorY         = variable1[2].split("-");

                document.all.item('question_y').value       = questionY[1];
                document.all.item('implicit_type_y').value  = implicitTypeY[1];
                document.all.item('flavor_y').value         = flavorY[1];
                document.all.item('choice_y').value         = -1;
                }
                else
                {
                alert ("Please select a valid x-axis variable");
                return;
                }
                var variable2 = document.all.item(axis2).value.split(".");

                if (variable2[0].indexOf("error") == -1)
                {
                var questionX       = variable2[0].split("-");
                var implicitTypeX   = variable2[1].split("-");
                var flavorX         = variable2[2].split("-");

                document.all.item('question_x').value       = questionX[1];
                document.all.item('implicit_type_x').value  = implicitTypeX[1];
                document.all.item('flavor_x').value         = flavorX[1];
                document.all.item('choice_x').value         = -1;
                }
                else
                {
                alert ("Please select a valid y-axis variable");
                return;
                }
```

]]>
                
This following input element contains a call to the above function, literally right below it. IE 10 does not want to recognize that it's a function?!?!

```
            <input class="popuButton" type="button" value="Go!" onclick="SubmitCross();"/>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
```

Comment: Why did you tag this "xslt"?

Comment: When I tagged it, I wasn't sure if the solution would envolve xslt, as it turned out it did. The file is an xslt(or proprietary version) and required an html doctype declaration wrapped in a xsl:text tag. So, xsl file, xsl solution, xslt tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the "< ! [CDATA[" does for you. But my bet would be that your function has definition errors. Try debug your javascript. Seems you missed the closing '{' bracket?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on this one. This is a function that worked for years with other browser versions. I know there is some deprecated code here, particularly as regards the document.all.item stuff, but there are no syntax errors outside of any I might have caused while copying. I'll doublecheck:)

Comment: By the way, CData refers to character data and is an instruction for the XML parser to not parse it as XML, which is exactly what we want for javascript embedded in an XML document, or in this case, an XSL doc, more or less the same for the purpose of this function.